# show file list in folder from using browser

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, browser

Normally if there is no htacces restriction is enabled it is possible to view the list of files under a folder hosted in web server using browsers. Except  if there exist a index file like index.php it automatically go to the index page. (as far i know)

But is it possible to see the list of files though there exist an index file ?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you would write what your motivation is, I think it would be much clearer what you ask for ;)

Comment: i have some images in folder along with an index.php file , i need to see the list of those images without accessing from the index.php file

Comment: Then make another file and point to that directory with the code below.  Should still suit your needs.  And you can just use an if statement to find out if they are images or not to display only those.

Comment: thanks, need to do this kind of modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. All web servers I'm aware of will only ever display a directory listing if there is no index page available (and, even then, only if directory listings are not disabled).

Comment: is it possible to stop the execution of index file from client side ?

Comment: No. That would be considered a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Build a file listing in PHP and display it in the index file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php .  I used this for a client to display certain file types in a directory through the index.php file.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the web root directory a sindex.php

```
<?php
$pngFolder = <<< EOFILE
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
EOFILE;

if (isset($_GET['img']))
{
       header("Content-type: image/png");
        echo base64_decode($pngFolder);
        exit();
}


$projectsListIgnore = array ('.','..'); 
$handle=opendir(".");
$projectContents = '';
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{
    if (is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$projectsListIgnore)) 
    {       
        $projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    }
}
closedir($handle);

?>
<ul class="projects">
<?php $projectContents ?>
</ul>
```